# Can I use emacs to execute elisp files witout opening emacs?

Tags: batch-mode

```
#!/usr/bin/clisp

(write-line "Hello World")
```

If I put this in a script it prints `Hello World` as expected.

What I'm wondering is there a way to use `emacs-nox` instead of `clisp` in the shebang and have it work the same way.

Comment: What's `emacs-nox`? What does this have to do with using Elisp files - where's the Elisp file in what you wrote?

Comment: @Drew `emacs-nox` is Emacs without the graphical interface. It only runs in a terminal. I thought that was standard, but maybe the name `emacs-nox` is specific to Debian/Ubuntu.

Comment: Maybe it's well known. But saying what it is in the question might help some readers. Please put all relevant info in the question itself, as comments can be deleted at any time. Thx.

Comment: The best thing to read: https://lunaryorn.com/blog/emacs-script-pitfalls/

Comment: Duplicate Q&A at S.O.: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10210742/run-elisp-program-without-emacs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `--script` flag to run an elisp file as a script:

```
 #!/usr/bin/emacs --script

<-- Insert your elisp program here -->
```

See the manual page on [Initial Options](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Initial-Options.html) for more details.